# Display google maps inside a fragment

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, fragment, androidx

**I am using kotlin and I want to implement the google maps into my androidx application inside a fragment.**

> I've tried mapView and it doesnt display any map when i run the app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mapView inside your activity and the implement the fragment as

```
    public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)          {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
  }

}
```

Comment: the above answer should work just instead of  map = mapView.getMap(); use mapView.getAsyncMap(this) and implement OnMapReadyCallback and in override method @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    }

Comment: This isn't working for me. I actually working with fragments only. When I added  mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState) it gives me an error that "Smartcast to mapView is impossible because it is a mutable property"